# How to use eb init without manual instructions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I want to make an `eb deploy` in a clean environment. It tells me I first need to execute `eb init`.

When I do this I see the following:

```
Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
14) ca-central-1 : Canada (Central)
15) eu-west-2 : EU (London)
(default is 3):
```

As you can see the setup needs manual instructions. 
How can I automate this setup?

I tried

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxx"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="xxx"
$ eb init
```

But again it was necessary to choose the region etc (like above)?

How can I autogenerate my `.aws` to make an eb deployment without manual interaction, only commands?

**EDIT**
I tried:

**init --region eu-west-1 appname**

This brought me already a bit further but now I receive:

```
Select the default environment.

You can change this later by typing "eb use [environment_name]".
1) app-dev
2) app-uat
```

How can I automate this setup in my `eb init` command?

Comment: `eb init` just writes some config files right? No reason you have to use eb init for that.

Comment: So I can make an eb deploy without doing eb init first? Because after setting env vars and doing my eb deploy it tells me: ERROR: This directory has not been set up with the EB CLI
You must first run "eb init".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 1. I want to make an `eb deploy` in a clean environment. It tells me I first need to execute eb init.

Looks like you've solved this problem, but I'll clarify anyway: The EBCLI requires that the present working directory be rooted at an `eb init`-ed application. The EBCLI looks for a `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` directory to determine whether the PWD has  been `eb init`-ed. Almost all `eb` operations require the PWD to have been `init`-ed with a Beanstalk application.

> 2. EDIT I tried: `eb init --region eu-west-1 appname ...`

You're almost there. In order to suppress the interactive mode, which is what you are trying to do, you need to pass the `--platform` flag. I can clearly see how inconvenient this is, but what you need is:

`eb init --region eu-west-1 --platform <platform-name> appname`

Where `<platform-name>` is the name of the language your app is in. Passing the `--platform` argument suppresses the interactive mode according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html).

Once that is done, you can execute:

- `eb use <environment name>` followed by `eb deploy`, or just
- `eb deploy <environment-name>`

Comment: I can't get this to work either. The documentation is very poor. I tried eb init pathfinder --platform arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Puma with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.0 | and got the error | eb: error: unrecognized arguments: with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.0 |

Comment: Looks to me like some sloppy regex is going on in the background

Comment: This is a common problem while interacting with shells -- enclose the platform name within quotes -- `eb init pathfinder --platform "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Puma with Ruby 2.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.0"` should work. If it doesn't, then it indeed is a regex problem.

Comment: Tried in quotes and out of quotes, every which way. No joy. I've given up on Elastic Beanstalk for the time being, the documentation is just so bad.

Comment: Okay, you could also write feedback on AWS Forums. (Also, FWIW, I think what's missing from the above suggestion is the `--region` argument, if I think I know what your problem is.)

Comment: Its still asks for environment name

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to develop a CI/CD, you can check my Jenkinsfile [here](https://gist.github.com/shqear93/46b68bc5080cffc9378de57aa40748e9)

You can pass input to `eb deploy` command using `printf` command:

```sh
printf '\n\n\n\n\n' | eb init ${EB_APPLICATION} --region ${AWS_REGION} --platform ${EB_PLATFORM}
```

Comment: its working for me thanks for posting this. I'm trying to deploy multiple regions using the BitBucket pipeline.  Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed EBS deployment from Azure DevOps, using cmd task with eb init by adding this

--platform "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.3.0"

full command

eb init --profile eb-cli --region us-east-1 --platform "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.3.0" ${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT }} -v

I got this with eb profile show command