# Pre-provided parameters to command with required prompt in SHELL

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prompt

So I have to make deployment of AWS Elastic Beanstalk application with AWSEB CLI on Jenkins. When i try to use command

```
eb init
```

It requires some information and credentials. Credentials are stored as parameters or could be a secret file on Jenkins instance. Command have no such things like --parameter to provide it at start. Is there any solution to provide all parameters in the code that in runtime this command will now okay now this is provided now this and so on? Something like this:

```
eb init --username XXX --password XXX --others XXX
```

Here is documentation for that command
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692554/how-to-use-eb-init-without-manual-instructions) help your issue? It seems you can set some of the parameters as Environment variables and rest as flags.. For example.

```bash
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxx"
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="xxx"
```

Then

```bash
eb init --region eu-west-1 --platform <platform-name> appname
```

Comment: Hi that actually seems like it works, but I am getting this http request error 403 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.' I know this are valid credentials and I am trying to set them up in the same way as you showed me above :/ Do you happen to know why it appears?

Comment: @JaniszewskiMarcin Check the troubleshooting guide here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html